# Deserializing XML element with attributes into list of strings

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an XML

```
  <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.keycloak/keycloak-services@10.0.2?type=jar">
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail@1.6.4?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.glassfish/jakarta.json@1.1.6?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet/jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec@2.0.0.Final?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core@4.0.7?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging@3.4.1.Final?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec@2.0.1.Final?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec@2.0.0.Final?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider@3.11.2.Final?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer/owasp-java-html-sanitizer@20191001.1?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations@2.10.1?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/com.openshift/openshift-restclient-java@8.0.0.Final?type=jar"/>
        <dependency ref="pkg:maven/com.webauthn4j/webauthn4j-core@0.10.2.RELEASE?type=jar"/>
    </dependency>
```

I am not sure how to deserialize this XML as the model shown below using System.Xml.Serialization in c#

```
     [XmlType(TypeName = "dependency")]
     public class Dependency
     {

        public Dependency()
        {
            this.DependsOn = new List<string>();
        }

        [XmlAttribute("ref")]
        [JsonProperty("ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [XmlArray("dependency")]
        [XmlAttribute("ref")]
        [JsonProperty("dependsOn")]
        public List<string> DependsOn { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this model, because I would like to use the same model for both JSON and XML deserialization

The JSON sample looks like this

```
"dependency": {
      "ref": "pkg:maven/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final?type=jar",
      "dependsOn": [
        "pkg:maven/org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec@2.0.1.Final?type=jar",
        "pkg:maven/org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec@2.0.0.Final?type=jar",
        "pkg:maven/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams@1.0.3?type=jar",
        "pkg:maven/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api@2.0.2?type=jar",
        "pkg:maven/org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec@2.0.1.Final?type=jar",
        "pkg:maven/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation@1.2.1?type=jar",
        "pkg:maven/commons-io/commons-io@2.6?type=jar",
        "pkg:maven/com.github.stephenc.jcip/jcip-annotations@1.0-1?type=jar"
      ]
    }
}
```

I tried the above, but I am getting an error Xml attribute cannot be used in conjunction with XmlArray, Could someone please help me with this scenario

Comment: Do you have to use XML deserialization rather than just querying the XML document directly? (It's not clear to me why you're modelling the "depends-on" part as a list of strings rather than a list of `Dependency` objects, mind you...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I am trying to use the same model for both Json as well as XML. I couldn't add json sample in the comment so, I have edited the orignial question.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171596/invalidoperationexception-when-serializing

Comment: Fundamentally those look like different models to me. The XML model would allow further nesting of `<dependency>` elements - the JSON model wouldn't. What do you have control over? Do you have to use XML serialization/deserialization? Are the formats set in stone? Please provide more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I am using them for both JSON/XML Serialization and deserialization. The model do  have lot of other properties as well, but they are the exact same for both the schema, except for dependency.  Yes the schema for the formats are not changable.

Comment: You still haven't said whether you *have* to use XML serialization/deserialization. Saying that you *do* use that isn't the same thing. I suspect if you want to do something non-standard like this, you'd be better off handling it directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I have mentioned in my previous comment, yes i have to use XML serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve your problem.
`XmlSerializer` is very flexible. The simplest way is to subscribe to the `Unknown*` event. And in its handler, manually implement the receipt and saving of the necessary data.

Full code example:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open);
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dependency));
ser.UnknownElement += Serializer_UnknownElement;

var dependency = (Dependency)ser.Deserialize(fs);

Console.WriteLine(dependency.Ref);
Console.WriteLine(dependency.DependsOn.Count);
foreach (var value in dependency.DependsOn)
    Console.WriteLine(value);

Console.WriteLine();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dependency, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);

void Serializer_UnknownElement(object? sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Element.Name == "dependency")
    {
        var refAttr = e.Element.Attributes["ref"];
        if (refAttr != null)
        {
            var dependency = (Dependency)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
            dependency.DependsOn.Add(refAttr.Value);
        }
    }
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "dependency")]
public class Dependency
{
    public Dependency() => this.DependsOn = new List<string>();

    [XmlAttribute("ref")]
    [JsonProperty("ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonProperty("dependsOn")]
    public List<string> DependsOn { get; }
}
```

XML deserialization works fine.

Note that serialization to JSON does not give the result you want.